# why doesn't ag in my vimrc ignore multiple patterns

Tags: search, the-silver-searcher

I have this in my .vimrc:

```
" The Silver Searcher
if executable('ag')
  " Use ag over grep
  set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor\ --ignore\ wiki --ignore\tests    
endif

" bind \ (backward slash) to grep shortcut
command -nargs=+ -complete=file -bar Ag silent! grep! <args>|cwindow|redraw!
nnoremap \ :Ag<SPACE>
```

it doesn't work, everytime I run vim i get this error

```
Error detected while processing /Users/abdullah/.vimrc:
line   52:
E518: Unknown option: --ignore\tests
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

when i press <kbd>\</kbd> it gives me `:Ag` in the prompt, but then doesn't ignore the `tests` directory (just the wiki one).

although if I do the same from the command line, it works just fine:

```
ag --nogroup --nocolor --ignore tags --ignore tests %search_term%
```

what am i missing?

Comment: I think you need a whitespace in your command. Your mapping is `--ignore\tests` while your working command is `--ignore tests`. Your mapping should be `--ignore tests` (or `--ignore\ tests` if the space needs an escape)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't escaped your command correctly:

```
set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor\ --ignore\ wiki --ignore\tests
                                                    ^        ^
```

There is a missing backslash after `wiki` and a missing space before `tests`.

Vim is therefore interpreting this as if it were two set commands:

```
set grepprg=ag\ --nogroup\ --nocolor\ --ignore\ wiki
set --ignore\tests
```

`--ignore\tests` isn't a Vim option, hence the error. And you're therefore also not passing that `ignore` argument to `ag`, so the `tests` directory is not ignored.

N.B. It's easier to set options including whitespace using `let`:

```
let &grepprg = "ag --nogroup --nocolor --ignore wiki --ignore tests"
```

#### Further reading

- `:h :set-args` (the bit right down the bottom, before `:set-verbose`)
- `:h :let-option`

Comment: ok cool.. bonus question: what's `grepprg` anyways? why is it shoved into the middle of all of this?

Comment: @abbood It's used to override the command that is used when you run Vim's `:grep` command. See `:help 'grepprg'`. `:grep` is used by the `:Ag` plugin you've installed under the hood to do the actual searching. Try using `:grep` instead of `:Ag`.

Comment: I would recommend using the `--vimgrep` option instead of `--nocolor` and `--nogroup`. It also has the added bonus of finding multiple matches per line just like `:vimgrep /pat/g`. e.g. `let &grepprg = 'ag --vimgrep --ignore wiki --ignore tests $*'`. If you use `--vimgrep` you should also set `'grepformat'` to `set grepformat=%f:%l:%c:%m` according to `man ag`.